# How to automatically remove debug statements for FirePHP?

Tags: php, debugging, firephp

`FirePHP` asks me to add debug function call on every .php page:

```
require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
ob_start();
```

It ist't a problem on my local machine. But I want to remove/disable them when my code is working in real world.

Is there any "debug mode" variable to disable them or tool to remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a constant

```
define('IS_PRODUCTION', false);
```

and use it later:

```
if (!IS_PRODUCTION) {
    require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this define()? A .php which is included by each other .php?

Comment: @Lai Yu-Hsuan: You should have a Configuration file somewhere, containing details which are constant, and reused, throughout your website (like the database username/password/hostname, etc.) and that file is `include()`'d or `require()`'d once in every other PHP file on the site. So you would just include @zerkms' `define()` within that file, maybe even the `if()` section as well, and then you can switch FirePHP on and off very easily.

Comment: this will produce an error if logging outside the if, better disable by $firephp->setEnabled(false); as mentioned by @cadom

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE:** If you remove the *FirePHP* include call but still have *FirePHP* logging calls in your code you will get a fatal error!

The proper solution is to **disable [FirePHPCore 0.3](http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Install.htm)**:

```
$firephp->setEnabled(false);
```

See [API reference](http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Use.htm) for more information.

All pages/scripts in your application/website should call a central [bootstrap file](http://devzone.zend.com/article/70) before doing anything else. The code above should be in this bootstrap file which will allow you to easily disable *FirePHP* for the entire application when deployed:

`bootstrap.php` ~

```
ob_start();
require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
// always disable FirePHP first - best practice
$firephp->setEnabled(false);
// only enable if in dev environment - best practice
if ($isDevMode) {
    $firephp->setEnabled(true);
}
```

FYI, If using [FirePHP 1.0](http://reference.developercompanion.com/Tools/FirePHPCompanion/Introduction/) logging messages will only be sent if an authorized client is detected eliminating the need for the code above.

Answer (score 0):

**followup to cadorn:**
If in your framework FirePHP is an *optional* install (addon,plugin,..) someone could eventually dissable or uninstall completely, you might consider to check FirePHP class or functions availability in your frameworks *core* via `class_exists()` or `function_exists()`, and in case FirePHP is out of reach, define subsititute functions. That way, you can avoid fatals, and eventually give some feedback/ouput alike "FirePHP not available"..